# Sufficient conditions for a system of linear inequalities to admit a solution

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, systems-of-equations, simplex

I am looking for sufficient conditions such that a system of linear inequalities of the type $A x >0$ admits a non-negative solution $x \in \mathbb{R}^n_+$. I know a few properties of the $m \times n$ matrix $A$

1. All entries are either $0,1$ or $-1$.
2. For each row $i$ there exists at least one column $j$ such that $A_{ij}=1$.
3. There exists at least one column $j$ such that $\sum_{i} A_{ij}=1$.

Do you know of any literature that studies sufficient conditions of this type?

Comment: You may get more responses on [or.se].

Comment: Posted also on MO: [Sufficient conditions for a system of linear inequalities to admit a solution](https://mathoverflow.net/q/334934). It is [recommended](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5085/moderator-supported-official-guidelines-for-legitimate-crossposting/5088#5088) to link to other copies of the question when [meta-tag:cross-posting].

Comment: Thanks a lot, for pointing me to or and the advice I did not know about the linking policy.